# What does parameter key mean in dataframe.to_hdf()

Tags: python, pandas

```
DataFrame.to_hdf(path_or_buf, key, **kwargs)
```

In pandas official document, it is said that key is identifier for the group in the store.
But what does that mean? Still, I cannot find sufficient examples for that. I have tried some arbitrary values for parameter key, but I didn't see any difference between them. Sometimes, the api reference can be quite ambiguous. Can anyone offer me some examples to help me to have a better understanding of parameter key?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In pandas to_hdf, the 'key' parameter is the name of the object you are storing in the hdf5 file.  You can store multiple objects (dataframes) in a single hdf5 file.  So for instance, you can store dataframe 'xyz' AND dataframe 'abc' in the same file, so in this case you would use key='xyz' if you wanted to store dataframe 'xyz' in your hdf5 file.

The 'key' is basically whatever name you want to name the specific object you are storing.  It is like a 'key' in a dictionary.

Comment: So since I only stored one dataframe in a hdf5 file, it doesn't matter what the key is.